# How i can change tag name in spring batch xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I have a spring batch project to create xml file, that return this:

```
  <UNITS>
      <pojo.unitgen>
          <event>Z_RECEIVING_RESULT</event>
          <type>Receipt</type>
          <internalDeviceId>6</internalDeviceId>
          <imei>990000223446789</imei>
      </pojo.unitgen>
      <pojo.unitgen>
          <event>Z_RECEIVING_RESULT</event>
          <type>Receipt</type>
          <internalDeviceId>2</internalDeviceId>
          <imei>992000123456789</imei>
      </pojo.unitgen>
  </UNITS>
```

how i can change the tag 'pojo.unitgen' for 'unit'

This is my ItemWriter:

```
 <!-- write extracted Receiving data into a xml file -->
 <bean id="iwReceiving" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter"
     scope="step">
     <property name="resource" value="file:${Report.pathToSave}${Report.fileName}" />
     <property name="marshaller" ref="UnitMarshaller" />
     <property name="rootTagName" value="UNITS" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="UnitMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
     <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/>
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming, you have a class "UnitGen" inside package "pojo", right? 
Try to use the annotation "@XStreamAlias":

```
package pojo;

@XStreamAlias("unit")
public class UnitGen {
 ...
}
```

You probably have to set the annotated classes:

```
 <bean id="UnitMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
     <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/>
     <property name="annotatedClasses">
       <list>
         <value>pojo.UnitGen</value>
       </list>
     </property>
 </bean>
```

Comment: Good Day Hans, that's right the UnitGen is in package pojo, but i trying to use Xstream Alias doesn't work, i also use a RowMapper for generate the info this is a problem?

Comment: have you also tried to set the "annotatedClasses" using setAnnotatedClasses?

Comment: I'm not using hibernate I just want to create a flat XML file with spring batch, I'm using a marshaller and RowMapper, I do not know how to do that you indicate :c

Comment: I was not referring to JPA/Hibernate. Check the API for the XStreamMarshaller. There is a method setAnnotaedClasses. As far as I understand, you have to register classes with "@XStreamAlias", otherwise the annotation will not be noticed. I extended my answer above.